# cast IEnumerable<T> To Dictionary<int,T>

Tags: c#

I have a method with this return type :

```
IEnumerable<T>
```

I want to map this Method and fill in a Dictionary.
Expected result is: `Dictionary<int, T>`

```
Dictionary<int, LeaveTypeDto> leaveType = new Dictionary<int, LeaveTypeDto>();
LeaveType.GetList(string.Empty).ToDictionary<int, LeaveTypeDto>();
```

How can I do this?

**Note:** GetList return type is IEnumerable of LeaveType, and some fields bust be map in LeaveTypeDto and some fields in LeaveType:

```
"ID,Title,HourlyAvailable,..."
```

ID is unique and must be use as key in my dictionary, and other field must be map to LeaveTypeDto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the key, or the key and value, to take from an enumerable.

If I have a class like so:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I can write the following to get a `Dictionary<int, MyClass>`:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> values;
IDictionary<int, MyClass> valueDict = values.ToDictionary(t => t.Id);
```

or the following to get a `Dictionary<int, string>`:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> values;
IDictionary<int, string> valueDict = values.ToDictionary(t => t.Id, t => t.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

I Defined an Extention Method On LeaveType :

```
public static DTO.LeaveTypeDto ToDto(this DataModel.Timekeeper.LeaveType leaveType)
        {
            return new DTO.LeaveTypeDto
            {
                ID = leaveType.ID,
                Code = leaveType.Code,
                Title = leaveType.Title,
                DailyAvailable = leaveType.DailyAvailable,
                HourlyAvailable = leaveType.HourlyAvailable,
                ShiftBaseAvailable = leaveType.ShiftBaseAvailable,
                PredefinedRemaining = leaveType.PredefinedRemaining,
                Active = leaveType.Active,
                StandardLeaveType = leaveType.StandardLeaveType,
                NotRequestAutomaticaly = leaveType.NotRequestAutomaticaly,
                TemplateFileID = leaveType.TemplateFileID,
                ObligateChooseSubstituteForDailyLeave = leaveType.ObligateChooseSubstituteForDailyLeave,
                ObligateChooseSubstituteForHourlyLeave = leaveType.ObligateChooseSubstituteForHourlyLeave,
                ObligateChooseSubstituteForShiftBaseLeave = leaveType.ObligateChooseSubstituteForShiftBaseLeave,
                ObligateChooseInsertAttachment = leaveType.ObligateChooseInsertAttachment,
                CheckSubstituteLimit = leaveType.CheckSubstituteLimit,
                AbsenceRespiteYearXferLimitDays = leaveType.AbsenceRespiteYearXferLimitDays,
                AbsenceRespiteYearXferMode = leaveType.AbsenceRespiteYearXferMode,
                AbsenceRespiteYearXferValuesSummarize = leaveType.AbsenceRespiteYearXferValuesSummarize,
                DailyRequestRegisterRespite = leaveType.DailyRequestRegisterRespite,
                DayMaxHourlyMinutes = leaveType.DayMaxHourlyMinutes,
                DayWorkMinutes = leaveType.WorkingPeriodMaxHourlyMinutes,
                DecreaseAllOnNXOverflow = leaveType.DecreaseAllOnNXOverflow,
                DecreaseBasedOnMonthWorkingDays = leaveType.DecreaseBasedOnMonthWorkingDays,
                DecreaseDayWorkMinutesOnExtraWorkDays = leaveType.DecreaseDayWorkMinutesOnExtraWorkDays,
                DecreaseOnExtraWorkDays = leaveType.DecreaseOnExtraWorkDays,
                DecreaseOnHolidays = leaveType.DecreaseOnHolidays,
                HourlyInOFFDayAvailable=leaveType.HourlyInOFFDayAvailable,
                YearXferValuesSummarize = leaveType.YearXferValuesSummarize,
                YearXferPercentage=leaveType.YearXferPercentage,
                MaxContinuousDaysLimit = leaveType.MaxContinuousDaysLimit,
                HourlyRequestRegisterRespite = leaveType.HourlyRequestRegisterRespite,
                YearXferMode = leaveType.YearXferMode,
                MonthlyDaysLimit = leaveType.MonthlyDaysLimit,
                MonthlyXMinsLimit = leaveType.MonthlyXMinsLimit,
                YearXferLimitDays = leaveType.YearXferLimitDays,
                YearLimitDays = leaveType.YearLimitDays,
                MonthStorable = leaveType.MonthStorable,
                YearHourlyMinsLimit = leaveType.YearHourlyMinsLimit,
                MonthPreusable = leaveType.MonthPreusable,
                MonthlyNXMinsLimit = leaveType.MonthlyNXMinsLimit,
                MonthMaxHourlyMinutes = leaveType.MonthMaxHourlyMinutes,
                IncreaseAbsenceRespiteRemaining = leaveType.IncreaseAbsenceRespiteRemaining,
                DailyLeaveRequestCountPerMonthForOthers = leaveType.DailyLeaveRequestCountPerMonthForOthers,
                DailyLeaveRequestDurationPerMonthForOthers = leaveType.DailyLeaveRequestDurationPerMonthForOthers,
                ShiftLeaveRequestCountPerMonthForOthers = leaveType.ShiftLeaveRequestCountPerMonthForOthers,
                ShiftLeaveRequestDurationPerMonthForOthers = leaveType.ShiftLeaveRequestDurationPerMonthForOthers,
                HourlyLeaveRequestCountPerMonthForOthers = leaveType.HourlyLeaveRequestCountPerMonthForOthers,
                UseLeaveRequetLimitForOthersPerMonth = leaveType.UseLeaveRequetLimitForOthersPerMonth,
                DailyCountPerMonth = leaveType.DailyCountPerMonth,
                CheckMeritRemainingInUnpayedRequest = leaveType.CheckMeritRemainingInUnpayedRequest,
                DayMinHourlyMinutes = leaveType.DayMinHourlyMinutes,
                FirstPresenceRangeHourlyCountPerMonth = leaveType.FirstPresenceRangeHourlyCountPerMonth,
                FirstPresenceRangeLenght = leaveType.FirstPresenceRangeLenght,
                FirstPresenceRangeMaxHourlyLimit = leaveType.FirstPresenceRangeMaxHourlyLimit,
                FirstPresenceRangeMinHourlyLimit= leaveType.FirstPresenceRangeMinHourlyLimit,
                HourlyCountPerMonth = leaveType.HourlyCountPerMonth,
                HourlyLeaveRequestDurationPerMonthForOthers = leaveType.HourlyLeaveRequestDurationPerMonthForOthers,
                IsMonthMaxHourlyStorableToCurrent = leaveType.IsMonthMaxHourlyStorableToCurrent,
                LastPresenceRangeHourlyCountPerMonth = leaveType.LastPresenceRangeHourlyCountPerMonth,
                LastPresenceRangeLenght = leaveType.LastPresenceRangeLenght,
                LastPresenceRangeMaxHourlyLimit = leaveType.LastPresenceRangeMaxHourlyLimit,
                LastPresenceRangeMinHourlyLimit = leaveType.LastPresenceRangeMinHourlyLimit,
                MiddlePresenceRangeHourlyCountPerMonth = leaveType.MiddlePresenceRangeHourlyCountPerMonth,
                MiddlePresenceRangeMaxHourlyLimit = leaveType.MiddlePresenceRangeMaxHourlyLimit,
                MiddlePresenceRangeMinHourlyLimit = leaveType.MiddlePresenceRangeMinHourlyLimit,
                MonthMaxDailyDays=leaveType.MonthMaxDailyDays,
                MonthMaxHourlyStorable=leaveType.MonthMaxHourlyStorable,
                ShiftBaseCountPerMonth=leaveType.ShiftBaseCountPerMonth,
                SuspendsPersonnelStatus=leaveType.SuspendsPersonnelStatus,
                WorkingPeriodMaxHourlyMinutes=leaveType.WorkingPeriodMaxHourlyMinutes,
                YearXMonthMaxHourlyferLimitHours=leaveType.YearXMonthMaxHourlyferLimitHours,
                YearXMonthMaxHourlyferMode=leaveType.YearXMonthMaxHourlyferMode
            };
        }
```

and by this Line My problem Solved.:)

```
GetList(string.Empty).ToDictionary(lt => lt.ID, lt => lt.ToDto())
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `System.Linq`

```
GetList(string.Empty).ToDictionary(k => int.Parse(k.ID))
```

Note, the previous example is valid if `ID` is `string`, if it is `int` then even simpler

```
GetList(string.Empty).ToDictionary(k => k.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

If ID is part of `LeaveTypeDto`

```
var q = GetList(string.Empty).ToDictionary(b => b.ID);
```

else use the select overload to get index and then use `ToDictionary()`

```
var q = GetList(string.Empty).Select((element, index) => new { i= index, e = element }).ToDictionary(b => b.i, b => b.e);
```